# How to get pixel value of a grayscale image with 16 bits depth using libpng library?

Tags: c, image, image-processing, libpng

I have a grayscale image with 16 bits depth. I want get pixel value of the images using libpng library. But, output of my program is all pixel values of that image between 0 to 255 at all. I checked it with ImageJ software with that image and the fact that they are between 0 to 65535. i don't know where i went wrong. This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <png.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("sample.png", "r");

    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_infop png_info = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);

    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

    png_bytepp rows;

    png_read_png(png_ptr, png_info, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);

    int WIDTH      = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, png_info);
    int HEIGHT     = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, png_info);

    rows = png_get_rows(png_ptr, png_info);

    for (int h = 0; h < HEIGHT; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < WIDTH; w++) {
            printf("%d ", rows[h][w]);
        }   
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't tag programming languages that you don't use. If you have a C program, then don't add the C++ tag. C and C++ are two very different languages.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am a newbie in StackOverFlow. I am so sorry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change the types on the following lines:

```
unsigned short **rows;

rows = (unsigned short**)png_get_rows(png_ptr, png_info);
```

Comment: Thank you for your helping, Pixel values of the image have been between 0 to 65535. But they don't match with output of ImageJ software.

Comment: Oh! Please can you share the information needed to work out the problem - maybe using Dropbox or Google Drive because imgur on StackOverflow reduces, compresses and strips files. Useful information would be 1) the original PNG, 2) the output from your program for a few pixels and 3) the corresponding pixels as calculated by ImageJ (screen capture is fine). Thank you.